# How can I confidently set the attributes of dispatched objects using win32com

Tags: python, excel, attributes, win32com

I have been struggling to assign an attribute to an object (or is it an instance)

```
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible=0
srce=xl.Workbooks.Open('myexcelfile')
srce.CheckCompatibility='False'
```

If I query the srce object about its CheckCompatibility attribute I get a response of 'False'

```
>>> srce.CheckCompatibility
    False
```

So I am naively thinking I can save this anyway I want

> > > srce.SaveAs(r'c:\newtttxt14.xls',FileFormat=1)

But when I do that the Compatibility Checker dialog comes up.  I hit continue, the file saves and I then check the compatibility again.

```
>>> srce.CheckCompatibility
    True

So I again try to set it and this time I am successful

srce.CheckCompatibility='False'
```

I query it once more:

```
>>> srce.CheckCompatibility
False
```

Now when I try to save the file the Compatibility Checker Dialog does not appear, the file saves exactly was I want it to.

I need some certainty about being able to set the attribute of srce before I attempt to save the file in another format - can this happen in some other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I suspect what's happening is that saving the file in XLS form is resetting the value of `CheckCompatibility` since the default value of that property is True for Excel 97-2003 binary workbooks.

In any case, there are multiple reasons why Excel might display a dialog when saving a file, not just the compatibility checker. I suspect what you really want is to suppress dialog boxes so that no user interactivity is required when your script saves a file. You can suppress dialog boxes by adding:

```
>>> xl.DisplayAlerts = False
```

before your call to `srce.SaveAs(...)`.